# error converting const char* to char

Tags: c++, char

I am trying to convert one char variable to a const char variable but I have the below error . Content of variable char is ok, in this case is a "H" and "e" but when I convert to const char* I have the letter + something else after. Can you guys please tell me where I did something wrong ?

Please see the picture from link !

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <lmcons.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    char Body[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' };       // elements of char array


    int size = sizeof(Body);                          // get size of Body array
    char Line;

    std::cout << "Size : " << size << "\n";           // view the size of Body array

    for(int i=0; i<=size; i++)                        // for statement : from first element to the last element of array
    {                                                 // beginning  of for statement

    Line = Body[i];                                   // get each element from Body array and put to char variable

    std::cout << "Char : " << Line << "\n";           // view the content of char variable


    const char *Line2 = &Line ;                       // convert from from char to const char*


    std::cout << "Const char : " << Line2 << "\n";     // view the content of const char* variable

    }                                                  // end of for statement
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKKLi.png)

Comment: C strings are NUL terminated. You are missing that.

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<=size; i++)` Probleme here. As an exercise. Try to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
const char *Line2 = &Line ;
```

Doesn't magically create a string from your character; as a string must be Null (or 0) terminated you can't pass this pointer to cout as it's expecting multiple characters to be processed.  If you were to change it to be

```
char Line[2] = {0};  // 0 initialise all the chars
Line[0] = Body[i];
Line[1] = 0;         // completely not required, but just making the point

char* Line2 = &Line[0];   // there are other cleaner ways, but this shows explicitly what is happening
std::cout << Line2;
```

You would not have UB.

Comment: Why do you want to convert *Line2 as C-style string? Can't a char be referred by a const pointer and later dereferenced to get the value of char.

Comment: @coder3101 sure it can - and most of this doesn't make sense as anything other than a learning process; but the point is that cout; where it was being used, needs a null terminated string.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are accessing Body[5], when running the loop as

```
for(int t=0;t<=sizeof(Body);t++){}
```

if you remove that = sign it will be okay.

```
for(int t=0;t<sizeof(Body);t++){}
```

Also, try to convert

```
std::const char *Line2 = const_cast<const char *>(&Line );
```

Use `std::const_cast<>()` to convert non constant to constant data types.

Also to remove those extra things from console you need to dereference the const char *, if you directly use it. std::cout tries to print everything until null is encountered in case you pass it const char *

So,

```
std::cout << "Const char : " << *Line2;
```

Comment: Ok..thanks for remark but still my problem persist...please see the picture from link. Also with "=" sign or without sign I have the same problem from the picture.

Comment: It's worse than that.  Every single cout<< will be given a pointer to a char, that isn't null terminated.  ie at the start, the pointer will be 'h', <unknown>, <unknown>....   and the operator cout << char * will iterate though the string until it finds a null (ie 0) char.

Comment: @UKMoney what if I dereference that pointer to get the char. std::cout will manage that

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not terminating `Body` with a null char(`\0`). And the second problem is your loop you are trying to access something that is out of range. The code should be like this:

```
char Body[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };       // elements of char array

int size = sizeof(Body);                          // get size of Body array
char Line;

std::cout << "Size : " << size << "\n";           // view the size of Body array

for(int i=0; i<size; i++)                        // for statement : from first element to the last element of array
{                                                 // beginning  of for statement

Line = Body[i];                                   // get each element from Body array and put to char variable

std::cout << "Char : " << Line << "\n";           // view the content of char variable


const char *Line2 = &Line ;                       // convert from from char to const char*


std::cout << "Const char : " << Line2 << "\n";     // view the content of const char* variable

}                                                  // end of for statement
```

You need null char at the end of the any raw string in c/c++ language because this helps it understand the ending of the string.